# How can I display an image coming as a binary stream?

Tags: curl, images, binary

I would like to display an image that I am receiving from a `curl` command. For example, I would like to display it using Eye of Gnome. How can I do that?

Something like:

```
curl https://example.com/image.png --output - | eog
```

I would like to display it directly, not by saving it on the disk first.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ImageMagicks `display` for that:

```bsh
curl https://example.com/image.png --output - | display
```

If you are on X11 (or use XWayland), `feh` supports this also:

```bsh
curl https://example.com/image.png --output - | feh --scale-down -
```

Also, I think KDEs `gwenview` can do it:

```bsh
curl https://example.com/image.png --output - | gwenview /dev/stdin
```

Comment: Of course, ImageMagick is always the anseer. Thanks!